# CSS : border-radius and color not respected within table

Tags: html, css

I have a span element with border-radius and border-color.

It shows up well, but when in the table element the round effect is shown but the border around it becomes rectangular with no round corners.

Fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/1182/

In the fiddle

`span` with `Two` as text shows the round border in the desired color.

But the `span` with `One` as text which is within the `table` shows a rectangular border. The border-radius has got applied thougth, if you have a close look you can see a yellow oval.

Desired behavior is that the red border should be shown for both the spans in oval shape just aound the yellow oval.

Comment: every  display value acts differently - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: display:table-cell was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't set span one display property with table-cell block. Try other values: block or something else

Comment: display:table-cell was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with jsfiddle. Same code works using SO code snippet.

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.round-round {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="round-round"> One </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      Something else
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<span class="round-round"> Two </span>
```